# Is there any possibility to get the plain (MediaWiki-markup) source instead of HTML source of Wikipedia-pages via API?

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

As I asked above, I want to get the plain Wikipedia/Mediawiki-markup via the API instead of the HTML source code.

If I try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Test&prop=text&section=2&format=xml) I get the HTML source of the section and of course I've already read the documentation of the Mediawiki API but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation for `action=parse`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse) says you can use `prop=wikitext` to get the markup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! :)
I was looking for this option for ages before I asked here.